# When do I use 'to' and 'ing'? For example, the verb is read

Tags: verbs, ing

Which is the correct form?

- Try to read a book this holiday, you might find it interesting.
- Try reading a book this holiday, you might find it interesting.

So *try reading* or *try to read*?

Next question same verb:

- I tried reading a book this weekend, but it was too long.
- I tried to read a book this weekend, but it was too long.

Comment: This question is off-topic because you have not shown any research effort. This site should not be considered an alternative to simply practising English with a friend. You might like to consider joining our sister site [ell.se].

Comment: Per @curiousdannii (whose close-vote I can't seem to find)

Answer (score 5):

Both are grammatical, but with different meanings.

The basic meaning of *try*, "attempt", usually takes the *to* infinitive:

> Try to read the book, and if you can't get through it, tell me.

In the different sense of *try out*, or *see if you like*, it usually takes the *-ing* form:

> Try reading this book, and tell me if you like it.

Colloquially, the first form is often replaced by *try and*.

Comment: Nice separation.

Comment: An established user like yourself should known better than to answer clearly off-topic questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Either is correct with the following difference

- Try to read

is a suggested action like in 'Try to read the user manual first'

- Try reading

is a suggested method like in 'Try reading books to improve your vocabulary'

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, typically, 'to + v' suggests uncertainty,working kind like auxiliary verbs, for example

- I am glad to know you

To explain that using 'to know you' instead of 'know you ', we could expand the sentence to this

- I am glad because I can/am able to know you. 
  Another example would be
- He may be right
- He seems to be right

For 'v-ing' , it suggests something that already happened. For example,
- It must be raining now

Comment: How does it suggest uncertainty?